# Kill Application Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin

What event can I get to when user kills the application by selecting the button to show the programs that are running on the mobile and dragging up or down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **don't think** there is an event that triggered when people select the button to show the programs that are running on the mobile and dragging up or down in Xamarin.forms.

In Xamarin.forms, the `Application` class contains three virtual methods that can be overridden to handle lifecycle methods:

- OnStart - Called when the application starts.
- OnSleep - Called each time the application goes to the background.
- OnResume - Called when the application is resumed, after being sent to the background.

> Note that there is no method for application termination. Under normal
>   circumstances (i.e. not a crash) application termination will happen
>   from the OnSleep state, without any additional notifications to your
>   code.

Refer: [app-lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle)